# Initialize super class values for an already instantiated subclass object

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    int a;
    int b;
    public int getA() {
        return this.a
    }
    public int getB() {
        return this.b
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a
    }
    public void setB() {
        this.b = b
    }
}

class SuperClass {
    int c;
    public int getC() {
        return this.c
    }
    public void setC(int c) {
        this.c = c
    }
}
```

Assuming I already have an initialized `SubClass` object with `SuperClass` variables not initialized, how do I initialize the `SuperClass` variables for that `SubClass` object.

E.g.: a function returns a `SubClass` object with `a = 10` , `b = 10` and `c` not set (and hence 0). I have a `SuperClass` object with `c = 30`. How do I initialize the `SubClass` object to have `c = 30`, other than manually setting each value of the `SuperClass` object.

Comment: when you initialize, set SubClass#setC(30);

Comment: not sure what you are asking - please explain what problem you are facing.  What constructors do you have?

Comment: FIrst start by providing two classes that actually compile.

Comment: @FlyingZombie yeah thats what I have been doing .But it gets messy if the super Class has lot of variables.

Comment: why would you have the setter/getter being `private`?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I edited it to public. I did not care about the scope much as it was not pertinent to what i was asking . My bad .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done through reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
        subClass.a = 10;
        subClass.b = 10;

        SuperClass superClass = new SuperClass();
        superClass.c = 30;

        for (Field field : SuperClass.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.set(subClass, field.get(superClass));
        }

        System.out.println(subClass.c); // prints out 30
    }

}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    int a;
    int b;
}

class SuperClass {
    int c;
}
```

I would however recommend you to not use this approach and just implement a `merge(SuperClass superClass)` method in your subclass:

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    int a;
    int b;

    void merge(SuperClass superClass) {
        this.c = superClass.c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooh the reflection method looks fancy .The merge method is what I have been using though. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Imprfectluck Fancy, yes. Maintenance nightmare too.

Comment: Yea the merge method looks to be the better option here. And reflection method satisfied my curiosity. So accepting this answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    public int getA() {
        return this.a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return this.b;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    // you can do any you want with c
    public void setSuperC(int c) { 
        setC(c);
    }

}

public class SuperClass {
    private int c = 30;

    protected int getC() {
        return this.c;
    }

    protected void setC(int c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to show? How does this answer the question? Btw, you forgot to make `c` private.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen question is `initialise the SubClass object to have c = 30`, my answer is how to achieve that, any comments?

Comment: Yes, I have comments. First of all: you don't provide an answer, just a blob of code. Secondly, the question is *"[H]ow do I initialise the SubClass object to have c = 30. Other than manually setting each value of the superclass."* Your blob of code does not address that.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen OK, I updated my reply, is that resolve your question now?

Comment: No it does not. How will OP use your code to initialize the subclass object to have *c* = 30 ***without** manually setting the value*?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen sorry, I'm not able to understand what you want ^_^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136302/discussion-between-g-bob-and-robby-cornelissen).